# Spring Boot with read-only session for single sign on

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, single-sign-on, spring-session

We have a legacy Spring application (A) (that is not using spring-boot) that handles authentication and writes the session to Redis using spring-session (the data in Redis is stored as XML).

We now want to introduce a new application (B), using spring-boot `2.2.6.RELEASE` and spring-session `Corn-RC1`, that should be useable if a user has signed into (A) with `ROLE_ADMIN`. I.e. this can be regarded as a very crude way of doing single sign on. A user should *never* be able to authenticate in B (it'd like to disable authentication if possible), it should only check that an existing user is authenticated in the session repository (redis) and has `ROLE_ADMIN`. Both A and B will be located under the same domain so cookies will be propagated by the browser. I've tried various different ways of getting this to work, for example:

```kotlin
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class ServiceBSpringSecurityConfig : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    @Autowired
    fun configureGlobal(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
    }

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .and()
            .httpBasic().disable()
    }
}
```

but this will show the default login screen:

[image]

I've also tried removing this part entirely:

```
@Autowired
fun configureGlobal(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
}
```

but then it'll generate a default `user` and password and it does not seem to call the `configure` method (or the configuration doesn't work regardless).

How can I solve this?

Comment: Just to clarify you want the login page to appear only if user tries to access application A. If they try to access application B without any form of authentication then it shouldn't be redirected to login page?

Comment: Doesn't matter all that much if user gets redirected to the login page of app A, but it would be a nice bonus :) Never showing a login page on B is what I'm after.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to disable `formLogin` and `httBasic` on Application B and add a filter before spring's authentication filter `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter` or `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`. In the custom filter you will extract the cookie/header/token from the request object and based on that reach out to the redis cache for session details. This filter would then validate the session and create object of type `org.springframework.security.core.Authentication` and set that in the current `SpringSecurityContext`.

Below is the sudo code for this;

**ServiceBSpringSecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ServiceBSpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint()).and()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
        .httpBasic().disabled().and()
        .formLogin().disabled().and()
        .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN")

    http.addFilterBefore(authTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authTokenFilter() {
        return new AuthTokenFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthEntryPoint authEntryPoint() {
        return new AuthEntryPoint()
    }
}
```

**AuthEntryPoint**

```
public class AuthEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthEntryPoint.class);

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // Very generic authEntryPoint which simply returns unauthorized
        // Could implement additional functionality of forwarding the Application A login-page
        logger.error("Unauthorized error: {}", authException.getMessage());
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Error: Unauthorized");
    }
}
```

**AuthTokenFilter**

```
public class AuthTokenFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // extract some sort of token or cookie value from request
        token = request.getHeader("Token");
        if (token != null) {
            // Validate the token by retrieving session from redis cache
            // Create org.springframework.security.core.Authentication from the token
            Authentication auth = authFactory.getAuthentication(token);

            // Set the spring security context with the auth
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
        } else {
            // Do something if token not present at all
        }
        // Continue to to filter chain
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

As mentioned this is sudo code so some adjustment might be required. However the general gist of token based auth remains the same.